# Can we delete activity history for email messages sent,without deleting the record?

Tags: data-loader, defaults, platform-activity, oob

We have a requirement where we want to delete the activity history of the email messages sent. Is there a way to accomplish this without deleting the record itself. Please give insight of the issue and whether this is possible or not in Salesforce.

[image: Case Activity History]
Thanks.

[image: Case activity history with Description]

Comment: Do you mean delete the activity comments/description, but preserve the subject?

Comment: I want the activity history to not be shown in the Activity History Related list.One option is to delete the activity history but that deletes the activity record itself. Is there any other way to not show the activity history in the activity history related list

Answer (score 1):

`ActivityHistory` is a separate Object from the `Activities` (`Tasks` and `Events`) and `EmailMessage` Objects. Deleting ActivityHistory records would not affect the underlying Tasks, Events or Email Messages associated with them. ActivityHistory can be queried and records that are returned can be deleted (sent to the recycle bin) in a number of different ways depending on your requirements and a User's permissions. See the [Object Reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/object_reference.pdf) for more on ActivityHistory and the other objects related to it.

Comment: Hi this does not seems to be the case.They activity and activity history seem to be closely related to each other.Deleting the activity history deletes the activity record.

Comment: If you're using the links in your screen capture, the activity will indeed be deleted. It's a bit like Window's file history where clicking on the file name is also clicking on a shortcut to the file. You need to query ActivityHistory (I suggest you order by Date) and then delete the ActivityHistory you don't want to keep from the results that are returned in the query.  That way you're only operating on ActivityHistory and not on Activity as well.